# Size of queue is reset to 0 in for statement c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, queue, size

I dont now how to add 2 different data from vector_data to hpp_DE. In the second iteration (i = 1), size of hpp_DE is reset to 0.

```
struct Instr;
queue <struct> hpp_DE;
queue <struct> vector_data;  
//size of vector is 2;
for (int i = 0; i <= vector_data.size(); i++) {
                    Instr = vector_date.front();
                    vector_data.pop();
                    hpp_DE.push(Instr); 
 }
```

It should add in queue  hpp_DE two values, but I only get one value; the second is added. The first value from vector_data is gone from hpp_DE. Why is that happening?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: After changing your code so it actually compiles it works correctly for me (as long as `vector_data` contains no more than 2 elements, otherwise it doesn't work correctly as noted by bruno)

Comment: Your code snippet works for [tio](https://tio.run/##dZA9DsIwDIXn@hSWWFIhEDMNXQoDp0BRGiBSSUJ@GEA9e3FbECAgS5TnZ/t7kc7NZCPMoesm2sgm1Qr5OamkSngJ2obolTiVQN4QsMJbWwBoE/EktGE53iCrcGvIVkAWYr1cDkN4VeLRud168yVflIzW72oRBdXeXnOXwpFVLM//65DtrUfWA2hc4aKgi6/eZ86DviqWU2E67fHwxxl48bNt762J1Pez4YPGun@2MfHIO@wgDMjaxw9ImyJy/nSNnL0wVJWpG8rtVUzeUDBou@4O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
for (int i = 0; i <= vector_data.size(); i++) {
                    Instr = vector_date.front();
                    vector_data.pop();
                    hpp_DE.push(Instr); 
 }
```

the size of `vector_data` changes because of the *pop* and at the same time you increment *i* to compare it to the (modified) size, this is wrong if you want to copy all the elements.

You use *struct* as a type, strange

`vector_date` must be `vector_data`

With that :

```
int main()
{
  queue <int> hpp_DE;
  queue <int> vector_data;  

  vector_data.push(1);
  vector_data.push(2);

  for (int i = 0; i <= vector_data.size(); i++) {
    int v = vector_data.front();
    vector_data.pop();
    hpp_DE.push(v); 
  }

  cout << hpp_DE.size() << ':';

  while (!hpp_DE.empty()) {
    cout << ' ' << hpp_DE.front();
    hpp_DE.pop();
  }
  cout <<endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % g++ -pedantic -Wextra v.cc
v.cc: In function 'int main()':
v.cc:13: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
/tmp % ./a.out
2: 1 2
```

(Use `size_t` rather than *int* for the index to remove the warning)

But with

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  queue <int> hpp_DE;
  queue <int> vector_data;  

  vector_data.push(1);
  vector_data.push(2);
  vector_data.push(3);
  vector_data.push(4);
  vector_data.push(5);

  for (int i = 0; i <= vector_data.size(); i++) {
    int v = vector_data.front();
    vector_data.pop();
    hpp_DE.push(v); 
  }

  cout << hpp_DE.size() << ':';

  while (!hpp_DE.empty()) {
    cout << ' ' << hpp_DE.front();
    hpp_DE.pop();
   }
   cout <<endl;
}
```

that prints `3: 1 2 3`

If the goal it to copy all just loop while `vector_data` is not empty to do the copy, or just assign one into the other ?

Comment: No, it isn't. Because 1 <= 1 is true, and the second iteration goes on. hpp_DE.size() is always 0

Comment: @Flavinia the code you give cannot be the code you execute, it is not possible to compile it, that may explain the behavior difference

Comment: @Flavinia I edited my answer to give examples of execution